# Can't delete cookie with ngx-cookie-service

Tags: angular, cookies, angular5, ngx-cookie-service

Im using https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service
 delete not working properly , can any one help me to solve this or suggest any other plugin

Comment: this script is kinda useless just use the JS cookie or locale storeage belive me its enough https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp or  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Here is what worked for me: I added a base url when creating the cookie and I used that same name when deleting. It worked for me. For example:

Storing a cookie:

this.cookieService.set('http://localhost:4200/accessToken')

When deleting:

this.cookieService.delete('http://localhost:4200/accessToken')

Answer (score 3):

Use this way might helpful

```
this.cookieService.delete( 'customer' , '/' );
```

Where 'customer' is Name and '/' is path

Answer (score -3):

use js-cookie

Cookies.set('name', 'value');

Cookies.remove('name');

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie